# divisibility algorithm on an array of integers

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

You are given an array of positive integers A. You need to create a subset of the array A with the maximum number of elements with the property that however we take any two numbers of the subset (we can call it x and y), we have that gcd(x,y) is higher than 1. Print the elements of the subset.

For example, if we have n = 4 and the array is {15, 7, 10, 6}, the output needs to be {15, 10, 6}.

Is there any faster solution than backtracking?

Comment: This question belongs on [computerscience.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Is `n=4` the length of the original array?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think you have a better solution.  Transform this to a graph problem: each integer is a node; two nodes `i` and `j` have an edge connecting them **iff** gcd(i, j) > 1.

Now, you need to find the largest fully-connected subgraph, (a.k.a. a clique).  A little research will show you how to implement that.  It's not efficient, but it's more tractable and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to the [Clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). So no, there is no efficient solution for this (unless P = NP).